# Bi Publisher 12.2.1.3.0

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, bi-publisher

I installed and configured Oracle Bi publisher 12.2.1.3.0 and followed the Oracle document for the process.

I am encountering the following error when I try to access Oracle Bi publisher as an Administrator.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfpMz.png)

Comment: Can you confirm in Enterprise Manager that all the servers are started?

Comment: And also that you put the correct credentials in when building the domain and starting the service?

Comment: Yes,All the servers are started and is in running state.I am using the correct credentials